# Sharepoint 2010 and Silverlight Web part SL version

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site with a Silverlight web part. When someone comes to the page that does not have silverlight it asks them to install the client. However, the link that sharepoint renders for the web part is for Silverliht 3 and not Silverlight 4. I have put the MinRuntimeVersion to 4.0 because that is the version of Silverlight the code is running. When the person downloads the SL version 3 and comes back to the Sharepoint website they are then asked to upgrade to SL 4. This is not what I would like it to do but how do I force Sharepoint 2010 to use

```
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
```

In the object tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by NOT using the Silverlight webpart. just a regular page and added my own html for the object tags.